# Pandas .Split If Else

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, jupyter-notebook

I've created a program so that I can split the dataset's column into 4 columns but some of my datasets only have 2 columns so when that section is reached, an error is thrown. I believe an if else statement can help with this.

Here is the code for my program:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
   
# reading csv file from url
filepath = "C:/Users/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/b 2 col.csv"
file_encoding = 'cp1252' 
data = pd.read_csv(filepath , header=None, names = list(range(0,4)) , encoding=file_encoding)

data.columns =['ID', 'Name',  'S ID', 'SName']

# new data frame with split value columns
new = data["Name"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

# making separate first name column from new data frame
data["Last Name"]= new[0]

# making separate last name column from new data frame
data["First Name"]= new[1]

# new data frame with split value columns (2)
new = data["SName"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)

# making separate first name column from new data frame
data["S Last Name"]= new[0]

# making separate last name column from new data frame
data["S First Name"]= new[1]

# Saving File name as its path
filename = os.path.basename(filepath) + ".xlsx"
data.to_excel(filename, index=False)

data
```

This section onwards is responsible for the splitting of the second set of data

```
# new data frame with split value columns (2)
new = data["SName"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)
```

Problem is not all of my CSV have four columns, so if I can implement an if else here to check if  data is present then proceed else skip and move to the next section:

```
    # Saving File name as its path
filename = os.path.basename(filepath) + ".xlsx"
data.to_excel(filename, index=False)

data
```

I believe the program would work with my datasets

Link to an example of my datasets: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nkLgo5tSFsxOTCa5EMWZlezDFi8AyaDq?usp=sharing

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, assuming the (`.csv`) files are in the same folder, here is a proposition with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filepath = "C:/Users/username/folder1/folder2"
file_encoding = "cp1252"

list_df = []

for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filepath, filename),
                         header=None, encoding=file_encoding, on_bad_lines="skip")
        df = (pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:i+5].pipe(lambda df_: df_.rename(columns={col:i for i, col in enumerate(df_.columns)}))
                        for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 5)], axis=0)
                  .set_axis(["ID", "FullName", "Street No", "Street Add 1", "Street Add 2"], axis=1)
                  .dropna(how="all"))
        df.insert(0, "filename", filename) #comment this line if don't want to show the filename as a column
        
        list_df.append(df)
                
out = (pd.concat(list_df, ignore_index=True)
           .pipe(lambda df_: df_.join(df_["FullName"]
                                        .str.split(", ", expand=True)
                                        .rename(columns={0: "FirstName", 1: "LastName"}))))
```

Output :

```
print(out.head())
​
          filename   ID       FullName    Street No  Street Add 1  Street Add 2 FirstName LastName
0  a 4 col upd.csv  NaN           Name          NaN           NaN           NaN      Name     None
1  a 4 col upd.csv  1.0   Bruce, Wayne  Street No 1  Street Add 1  Street Add 2     Bruce    Wayne
2  a 4 col upd.csv  2.0  James, Gordon  Street No 2  Street Add 2  Street Add 3     James   Gordon
3  a 4 col upd.csv  3.0   Fish, Mooney  Street No 3  Street Add 3  Street Add 4      Fish   Mooney
4  a 4 col upd.csv  4.0   Selina, Kyle  Street No 4  Street Add 4  Street Add 5    Selina     Kyle
```

Comment: Okay I see that it works when I add in `, names = list(range(0,10))` to `...header=None, skiprows=1, encoding=file_encoding...`, is there a better way to solve the error: `
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 55, saw 10` ?


Also can you make a minor tweak, I would like the addresses to be separate so maybe in the header/column name `Street No`, `Street Add 1` and `Street Add 2`? And the first row of data is deleted, so I suppose to see "Name" above "Bruce Wayne" name. Thanks for all your input thus far :}

Comment: For `1)`, I still think you don't need to add a range of numbers as names because we're renaming the columns names with `df.rename` one line below. For `2)`, It's hard for me to figure out why you're getting a `ParseError` without having an example of .csv/line that cause the errror. However, you can add `on_bad_lines="skip"` to `pd.read_csv`. For `3)`, I will update my answer acoordingly. For `4)`, you can remove `skriprows=1` from `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251425/discussion-between-kenny-and-timeless).

Comment: Is there a way the extension of  ` filename` can be removed? Instead of having `a 4 col upd.csv`, there could be `a 4 col upd`? Or just show filename till `.` since I have some filenames with multiple extensions for example, `a 4 col upd.pdf.csv`

Comment: Yes, use `df.insert(0, "filename", filename.split(".")[0])`.

Comment: Appreciated, I tried to put an output for when the program is complete but I'm not sure which variable is responsible ? `print(out, " is done.")` it should say `Concat.xlsx is done`

Answer (score 0):

You can split your 2 column to 4 column like that.

```
#if there are some missing columns
data['First Name'] = np.nan
data['Last Name'] = np.nan
data['S First Name'] = np.nan
data['S Last Name'] = np.nan
#if there is not missing values remove above

data[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = data.Name.astype(str).str.split(",", expand=True)

data[['S First Name', 'S Last Name']] = data.SName.astype(str).str.split(",", expand=True)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: Try:  data[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = data.Name.astype(str).str.split(",", expand=True)

Comment: Getting another error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` with the dataset `b 2 col.csv`

Comment: firstly print(data.info()) and look if there any na value or not.If there are any NA value you can split your data into 2 dataset for example df1 and df2(na) and apply it on df1 then concatenate them with frame = [df1,df2] then data = pd.concat(frame) lastly data = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Actually I cannot create your problem in my workspace and I cannot be sure what is problem.

Comment: Yes that looks good, that's what the other answer have but implemented differently, unfortunately I'm new to coding so actually implementing your suggestion is far fetch for me. If you can make those changes to your answer I would appreciate it.